# Connecting Light Table to a remote REPL

Tags: windows, clojure, leiningen, read-eval-print-loop, lighttable

I cloned a [sample Chortles project](https://github.com/technomancy/chortles) to test out the remote REPL capabilities of drawbridge. I can connect using `lein repl :connect http://user:pass@localhost:5000/repl` and dereference `scores` with `@chortles.web/scores` in the REPL, which correctly yields a vector of past scores, e.g. `[0 0 7]`.

However, when I connect to the same URL in Light Table, an empty vector is returned when dereferencing `scores`. Why is Light Table not returning the known value of `scores` even though it reports the connection as successful?

I hard-coded the test authentication values in the sample project and added the middleware settings required by Light Table to `project.clj`:

```
:repl-options {:nrepl-middleware [lighttable.nrepl.handler/lighttable-ops]}
```

Comment: How did you manage to create a "successful" connection from LT to the server?